# Why can't I ask broad, opinion-based questions?

Tags: discussion

Why can't I ask broad, opinion-based questions that could help answer some fundamental conceptual misunderstandings about programming.

Why does every question have to be a very specific question?

It's not that I don't see the value of having specific questions answered it's just not everything can be specified

Case in point:

You've gone through the tutorials, you know vars, arrays, functions, algorithms but when it comes time to sit down and just program you're lost. Now, what's wrong with asking the community of programmers *"hey, how do you go about tying all these concepts together, what are some strategies to help make me better at programming"*?

Yes this is a broad question that's bound to get a slew of opinionated responses but if just one person answers something that truly helps you expand your understanding and points you in the right direction, why does this question get closed?

I think there comes a point in programming that you have to ask broad philosophical questions to get any further.

Maybe my example question is a bad example but I was taught that the only stupid question is the one nobody asks.

Stack Overflow is hands down the largest supplier of technical expertise on a broad range of topics yet I don't post questions on here, questions that I desperately need answers to, due to ridicule and embarrassment.

The problem is I'm still trying to figure out the question and I'm not sure how to ask because I don't know what it's even called.

So please explain to me why this simply isn't allowed; why does everything have to fit inside a box, if one can prove mathematically that this idiom is counterproductive to what Stack Exchange actually exists for?

Comment: For exactly the same reason that they won't make you a perfect martini at the car wash. It's just not what the place is for.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Clearly you just need to find a better car wash if yours doesn't serve martinis.  It's the *only* way to get your car cleaned.

Comment: Ask them in a chat here.

Comment: Oh gawd.. no.  Please, no:(((

Comment: I hate Martini, and 'how do I program a computer' questions:(  Then again, I have to say that my car is very dirty...

Comment: 'how do you go about tying all these concepts together,': it is called experience,  It cannot be taught or acquired from SO Q&A.   Newbs need to DO STUFF instead of asking woolgathering nonsense.

Comment: SO is the largest supplier of technical expertise **because** it does not allow broad, open-ended and opinionated questions.

Answer (score 11):

Overly broad questions are off-topic because:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Opinion based questions are off-topic because:

> Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to [ opinion based questions ] will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Those two quotes are from the applicable close reasons.

The one commonality here is that both overly broad, and overly opinion based questions tend to generate large amounts of discussion and the content they garner tends to be a bad fit for the objective Q&A format.

If you want to ask overly broad or opinion based questions, there *are* places for that on the internet, Stack Overflow just isn't one of them. I recommend checking out [quora](https://www.quora.com) or [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/).

To further answer your question, the reason these questions get closed, even if they get good answers that help *you*, is because Stack Overflow is not about just helping the person asking the question. If that was what we were all about, we would undoubtedly be much more of a disastrous mess than we already are, removing any ability to find useful information for the task you're facing that we do have.

Stack Overflow is about creating a repository of useful solutions to specific programming problems that will be faced by programmers in the future. No one wants to expend effort solving problems that no one else is ever going to face, that just doesn't make sense. No one wants to put a whole bunch of effort into answering a question that is ultimately just going to get lost in the mix.

OK, I fudged a little bit there, people do want to do that, for whatever odd reason. But it just isn't useful at all in the broad scheme of things. It makes the good content harder to find, and the solutions to your problems further away.

Comment: I would think that a broad programming question would stand the best chance at being useful to other programmers down the road because its broadness could apply to a wider set of problems so would actually kill more birds with one stone. I see a lot of posts that because of the specificity don't really help you on your problem because it's too specific. If the goal is to create a repository of useful information and you can answer many peoples specific questions through generalization then you should encourage this behavior. Too a point. I wish there was one post that had all the answers :)

Comment: Being too specific is another problem entirely, and yes it is a problem. However, overly broad questions are harder to find, and don't solve specific problems, so even if you can find the answer, it is even harder to find the part of the answer, or answers, that solves the problem you're facing. Nonetheless, overly broad questions are not a good fit for this format, and the community at large has decided that we don't want those questions here.

Comment: I can understand that, my problem specifically is that I know the basics can program in any language but can't program more then algorithms. So I don't know what I'm missing to tie everything together, maybe there is some small piece that I'm missing that if I knew it everything would finally click. I've been stuck at this point for years now. Now How do I frame a question that will help me when I'm not sure what to ask? Is there a approach I should take in asking this kind of question to make it fit the format? I feel like I'm searching for something that I don't know the name of.

Comment: See, the biggest part of asking a question, and one of the reasons I rarely ask questions, is the whole figuring out what you're going to ask part. I'm not going to lie to you, asking a good question is incredibly difficult. However, you *can* figure out what you want to accomplish, do your absolute best to accomplish it, then come and ask a question including some example input, expected output, and what you've tried so far to accomplish the task, which would make the question much more narrow than what you've described so far.

Comment: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/117975/can-you-explain-the-following-c-script-for-camera-behavior

Comment: So is this too broad, maybe I'm trying to eat an elephant in one bite here but I just want to create a conceptual understanding based off what I know works to then apply to something else because I can't just write something new if I don't have a solid foundation of what each part is doing.

Comment: I'm not into moderating other sites and their content, but if I saw that on Stack Overflow I would vote to close it in a heartbeat as it is a very broad question. It asks too many questions and the questions it asks are too broad, not to mention "can you explain this code for me" requests are in and of themselves inherently too broad. We're not a good place for conceptual questions at all, but it's a great place for specific implementation questions.

Comment: So its great if you want someone to solve your problem for you but bad if you want help to be able to solve it yourself. How does this help anybody if you ask a question and show an answer but never talk about why the answer is the answer. But if your saying this is just a Q&A and there will be no explanation further then the answer to your question then I'll give it a rest and move on.

Comment: Great answers explain why the solution is the solution, how the author came about the solution, and what the solution does. Does every question get a great answer? No. The problem with conceptual questions is that there is often no objective answer. People can write blogs, and tutorials, and all sorts of things that deal with the conceptual part of programming, but this just isn't the place for that. If you have a specific question about a problem that you are actually facing (and not the problem of not knowing how to begin a task), then it is much more likely to be on-topic.