# Question put on hold despite soliciting discussions and useful answers

Tags: discussion

I have run into this a couple of times. Most recently [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36947716/5560474).

I asked a question which, despite the comments, did not simply ask for a recommendation. I asked a broad question and said, how do I begin researching this?

In my experience in a multi-disciplinary research setting, this is a typical and accepted way to start a discussion: I know my end goal, I know the tool I should be using, but I need guidelines in how to start my research. As in, what are the jargon words that come to mind for you, an expert, when you hear about my problem. Then I'll start looking into them.

In this case, since the tool I knew needed to be used was PHP (which I figured out by doing research and reading the PHP intro tutorial), I came to a place where there are PHP experts.

In this case, two people provided suggestions, and I looked into them, did additional research, came up with a solution, and marked one of the answers as accepted. Doesn't this accomplish the purpose of Stack Overflow? Or is the purpose to fend off people who don't yet have enough knowledge about things to ask pointed questions?

What's particularly frustrating is that the reason for putting my question on hold does not include a recommendation for a better place in the Stack Exchange community to ask the question.

Comment: Asking how and where to start on something when you have no clue whatsoever is not on-topic for SO because we don't provide free tuition or free design.  'does not include a recommendation for a better place to ask the question' - why would anyone wast... spend time looking up sites for you when they could be answering good questions that are on-topic?

Comment: 'Or is the purpose to fend of people who don't yet have enough knowledge about things to ask pointed questions?' - You imply that there are only two possibilities, the good one where you get all your research done for you by other SO users, or the bad one where newbs get fended off.  That is a gross misrepresetation and borderline insulting to the intelligence of SO contributors whom you seem to think will not understand the illogic of your argument:(

Comment: In all likelihood, if someone didn't recommend a better place to ask means they there isn't a suitable place on Stack Exchange.  While I sympathize with your plight, there are plenty of forums on the internet that you can ask such questions.  But Stack Overflow and other Stack Exchange sites are not one of them.

Comment: Closely related: [Are "how would I get started" questions too broad?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/308745), [Answering questions which ask for effort guidance, not spoon-fed solutions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254933), and [Where do questions that ask for programming technology solutions belong?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/320629)

Comment: Long answer short: SO *isn't* a multi-disciplinary research setting. If you don't know where to start, it's elsewhere.

Comment: @MartinJames - I clearly wasn't asking for free tuition or design. I asked for guidance on how to begin my own design. And I have edited the question to clarify - I meant, where on Stack Exchange does such a question belong? In the past, I have been helpfully pointed to Code Review (which I didn't know of) and Electrical Engineering (and told why my question was a better fit over there).

Comment: @LShaver the fact that you have pointed to other sites in the past simply reinforces the point in my comment.  If you didn't get a suggestion, there simply may not be a place for your question.

Comment: If there isn't a place in Stack Exchange for such a question, I can understand that. But the fact that my question did result in discussion, two helpful answers, and a solution to my problem, is evidence that perhaps it DID belong on Stack Exchange. The results were good, the question bad - so how should I have worded the question?

Comment: @MartinJames, I don't doubt the intelligence of the folks here, otherwise I wouldn't come asking! I was frustrated that my question was shut down so quickly - but thankfully not before getting some very helpful answers. And just to re-iterate, I wasn't looking for a spoon feeding! I spent the morning yesterday reading up on PHP, posted my question, then spent the rest of the day/evening getting my PHP scripts working with the help I was given.

Comment: see also: [Why can't I ask broad, opinion-based questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318651/why-cant-i-ask-broad-opinion-based-questions)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I sympathize with the problem of not knowing where to start, asking off-topic questions on Stack Overflow is not the way to go.  Stack Overflow is simply not a "do my research for me" tool.  If you don't know what you don't you know, it will be difficult to get help here.

> In this case, since the tool I knew needed to be used was PHP (which I figured out by doing research and reading the PHP intro tutorial), I came to a place where there are PHP experts.

Okay, so you started some research but still didn't narrow your problem down much.  You decided to come to come to Stack Overflow to find people to help you narrow your problem down.  The problem is, you asked a question that is out of scope for Stack Overflow.  Stack Overflow is designed to be a Q&A: a site to help solve **specific** programming problems.  The reason your question got closed is that it is not specific.

From your SO post in question:

> So my question as a complete newcomer to PHP is this: what features/functions/elements of PHP should I be reading up on to gain the knowledge I need to build this?

There are really no bounds to your question.  You are effectively asking "I have no clue what to do, can you tell me how to accomplish my goal or recommend a tool/library/function to do this".  Long ago, after a lot of experience with such questions, the community decided these types of recommendation questions are off topic due to the spam and other low quality answers that these types of questions attract.  You need to narrow the problem down significantly.

> In this case, two people provided suggestions, and I looked into them, did additional research, came up with a solution, and marked one of the answers as accepted. Doesn't this accomplish the purpose of Stack Overflow? Or is the purpose to fend off people who don't yet have enough knowledge about things to ask pointed questions?

We can't control what answers people provide.  Some people answer completely off-topic questions that aren't even remotely about programming, simply because they know the answer (or at least think they know the answer).  The mere presence of an answer doesn't automatically make the question on-topic.  It just means you got an answer to your question.

---

While all of this may seem overly pedantic and even harsh, the simple fact is that Stack Overflow is the resource that it is today is because the community is very aggressive in moderation.  Question (and answer) quality is strictly enforced in order to ensure the quality and reputation of the site is maintained.  If the rules were relaxed and all programming questions were welcomed, you would see the quality of the answers quickly fall as the experts on the site today would leave, and the site would no longer be the resource that it is.

Comment: This makes sense - thanks. So this means that either I should have A) gotten further in my project before posting on SO, or B) found another community/resource better suited to such "guidance" questions.

Comment: @LShaver exactly.  I think the best way to sum up when to ask a question, (A) when you have code and have a problem getting the code to work correctly; or (B) when you know what you don't know (meaning you know you need to accomplish a **small** task, but can't figure it out).....  When you don't even know where to start, that is a sign that asking on SO is the wrong approach

Comment: There's a great analogy about known unknowns and their place in an SO question [over on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215220/159251), @LShaver.